# how to find substring in main string and also search whether all the elements of substring are present in main string

Tags: java, string

I coded the first part and how to do the second part with less code? Which is  search whether all the elements of substring are present in main string?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner getString = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("provide the main string: \n");

    try {
        String str1 = getString.nextLine();
        System.out.println("provide the sub string: \n");
        String str2 = getString.nextLine();
        if (str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())) 
        {
            System.out.println("It is a substring");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("It is not a substring");
        } 
    } 
        finally 
        {
            getString.close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the second part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf()` method of the `java.lang.String` class to check whether every character of the sub string exists in the main string or not.

**The Logic:** Initialize a count variable `n`. Now, iterate through each character of the substring in a for loop. Check for each character whether it exists in the main string using the **indexOf()** function. If it exists, then increment **n**'s value by 1. Outside the loop, check if n == length of the substring. If n== length of substring, then **all elements of the substring exist in the main string.**

Consider the code below.

```
String main_str <--- MAIN STRING
String sub_str <--- SUB STRING
int n=0;
for(int i=0; i<sub_str.length();i++){        
    if(main_str.indexOf(sub_str.charAt(i))!=-1) 
    n++;
}
if(n==sub_str.length()) 
System.out.println("All elements of sub string EXIST in the main string");
else
System.out.println("All elements of sub string DO NOT EXIST in the main string");
```

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: Well, please note that the code is case sensitive, meaning that if the main string is `ABCDE` and the sub string is `abcde` then it'll say that sub string does not exist in main string since `'A' != 'a'` and so on. To make it case **insensitive**, just convert the main and sub strings to the same case using the `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `contains()` function do that already ? I mean if you use the `contains()` function then all the characters(elements) of `str2` are checked with all characters in `str1` and if all characters of `str2` are present in `str1` then and only then the `contains()` function will return `true`. So the second scenario is taken care of implicitly by the `contains()` function.

Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: for say str1 = oracle and str2 = acl, u r right in this case but what if str2=lca ?

Comment: I'm sure a solution without using library functions is wanted. That's why this code needs to be written.